# does $d\sim p$ imply $d\approx p$ in the metric space $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X\neq \emptyset$ and $M(X)\subseteq [0,\infty)^{X\times X}$ denote the set of all metrics on $X.$ For $d, p\in M(X),$ let

$d\approx p\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}\text{ there are $m, M > 0$ for which}\\
\text{ $m d(x,y) \leq p(x,y) \leq Md(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ }\end{cases}$

and

$d\sim p\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}\text{ $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,d)\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,p)$}\\\text{
 for any sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq X$ and $x\in X$}\end{cases}$

> Show that $d\sim p\in M(X)$ iff $(X,d)$ and $(X,p)$ admit the same open sets.

> Does $d\sim p$ in $M(X)$ imply that $d\approx p$? Prove or disprove this.

For the first part, I think I need to show that $\{O\subseteq X : \text{ $O$ is open in $(X,d)$}\} =\{O\subseteq X : \text{ $O$ is open in $(X,p)$}\},$ which I think can be done by double inclusion. I know that open sets are defined so that $O$ is open in $(X,d)$ if $\forall x \in O, $ there exists $\delta > 0 $ so that $B(x,\delta) := \{y \in X : d(x,y) < \delta\}\subseteq O$. Let $A$ be open in $(X,d)$. Then $X\backslash A$ is closed in $(X,d)$. Let $(y_n)\subseteq X\backslash A, y_n \to y$ in $(X,p).$ Then since $d\sim p, y_n\to y$ in $(X,d)$ and since $X\backslash A$ is closed in $(X,d), y \in X\backslash A$ so $X\backslash A$ is closed in $(X,p).$ Similarly, one can show that if $A$ is open in $(X,p),$ then $A$ is open in $(X,d).$

> However, I'm not sure how to show that if $(X,d)$ and $(X,p)$ admit the same open sets then $d\sim p.$

> As for the second part, I think it might be true and that a contradiction might be useful for showing it but I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: Pick your favourite metric $d$ and then consider $p(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. We have $d~p$, but in general not $d\cong p$ (pick $d$ unbounded).

Comment: Can you express $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,d)$ via open sets in $(X,d)$?

Comment: @PaulFrost what are you trying to imply? How would that be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It invokes the fact that a set $C$ is closed in $(X,d)$ if and only if all limits of sequences in $C$ are contained in $C$.

$d \sim p$ means that that the metrics are *equivalent* in the sense that

> $(*) \phantom{x}$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,d)  \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,p)$  for any sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq X$ and $x\in X$.

You certainly define $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in $(X,d)$ by the condition

> $(1) \phantom{x}$ For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

Let us show that this condition is equivalent to

> $(2) \phantom{x}$ For all open neigborhoods $U$ of $x$ in $(X,d)$ there exists $n_0$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

An open neigborhood of $x$ is simply an open set $U$ in $(X,d)$ such that $x \in U$. It is easy to see that all *metric balls* $B(\xi,\epsilon)$ are open (triangle inequality!). Moreover we clearly have $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$  if and only $x_n \in B(x, \epsilon)$. Therefore $(2)$ implies $(1)$ because each $B(x,\epsilon)$ is an open neigborhood of $x$. For the reverse implication it suffices to observe that each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains some metric ball $B(x,\epsilon)$.

Using $(2)$ it is clear that if $(X,d)$ and $(X,p)$ have the same open sets, then $(*)$ is satisfied, i.e. $d \sim p$. The converse has already been proved by you.

$d \approx p$ means that the metrics are *uniformly equivalent*. Clearly uniformly equivalent implies equivalent, but the converse is not true. As an example take $X = \mathbb R$ and $d(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$. Now define $p(x,y) = \min (d(x,y),1)$. it is easy to verify that $p$ is again a metric on $\mathbb R$. Clearly $(*)$ is satisfied, thus $d \sim p$. But $d \approx p$ fails; otherwise there would exist $m > 0$ such $md(x,y) \le p(x,y) \le 1$ for all $x,y$, i.e. $d(x,y) \le 1/m$, which is not true.